# How can I make a sentence to connect two seperate things?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I'm trying to land a summer job at this company and I did a group project on electricity as an alternative fuel so I was wondering how should I connect both of these things

I was thinking :

> As I have worked on the perspectives and challenges of electricity as
>   an alternative fuel, I was excited to learn that your company recently
>   decided to purchase electric cars and reduce its emissions

is this one correct ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems quite logical to me.

There are a couple more possibilities:

> Having worked on the perspectives and challenges of electricity as an alternative fuel, I was excited to learn that your company recently decided to purchase electric cars and reduce its emissions
>
> Since I have worked on the perspectives and challenges of electricity as an alternative fuel, I was excited to learn that your company recently decided to purchase electric cars and reduce its emissions

Comment: Thank you very much